# How to serialize an object and then send it over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm making a Battleships game and I want to send an Array of a class named Ships(which contains stuff like ship name, size, rotated or not and an arraylist for coordinates). I've googled this and looked on Stack overflow and I basically need to serialize the array, but this is where I'm stuck. I need to use ObjectOutputStream, but how do I encorporate that into the code below (taken from android dev site). Note I have already made the ship class implement serializable. Thanks in advance

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connectedthread started");
            // mHandler.obtainMessage(TEST).sendToTarget();
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {

                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created");
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Begin mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    Log.i(TAG, "reaaaad msg");
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SetUpGame.MESSAGE_READ2, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnectd");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote
         * device
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {

            try {

                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                Log.i(TAG, "writeeee msg");
                mHandler.obtainMessage(SetUpGame.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1,-1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write");
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close of connect socket failed");
            }
        }

    }
```

and my handler:

```
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ2:

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                break;

            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Me:" + writeMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

Comment: I developed a bluetooth system for Android to control stuff in a car... I'll post a Github link here tomorrow if it hasn't been answered already, I need to find the code

Answer (score 6):

In the code above you get input/output streams from the connected socket.

Now you can stream data to/from the socket using those streams.

How exactly you do this depends on the type of data you want to stream.  In this case you have a serializable Object to send, so you will wrap your stream in a filter that adapts the stream for use with Objects: ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream...

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( mmOutStream );
for (Ship ship: ships)
  oos.writeObject( ship );
```

This code iterates through the array of Ships, writing each ship to the stream (and hence, to the Bluetooth socket).

The receiving side is the same, with one additional complication: you don't necessarily know when to stop or what to read.  There are various schemes for handling this, and there are SO questions dealing specifically with this.  The Bluetooth page of the Android developer's guide has sample code for this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Oh ok thank you. How do I deal with it on the other side in the handler?

Comment: @user1953208 I added stuff about receiving to the answer.  Also, I suggest you look at the Bluetooth Chat sample in the SDK.

Comment: Can you provide some more info about receiving objects? Is it ```Ship ship = objectInputStream.readObject();``` ? Is that a blocking call?